# RadioGroup not working in fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-radiogroup

I have faced an issue radio check change listener not working in the android fragment, I tried this within an activity it will work fine, while I convert into fragment it will give no response, please help me, here is my code.

**K06_Away.java**

```
 public class K06_Away extends Fragment {

        private View kf06_view;
        protected Typeface tfLatoBold,tfLatoMedium,tfLatoRegular;
        private Button button_kf06_back,button_kf06_next;
        private TextView txtVw_kf06_resident_away;
        private EditText edTxt_kf06_visiting_lastname;
        private RadioGroup radioGp_kf06_resident_away;
        List<RadioButton> radioButtons = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            kf06_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.k06_away, container, false);

            return kf06_view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
                   configViews();
        }


        private void configViews() {
            button_kf06_back = (Button) kf06_view.findViewById(R.id.button_kf06_back);
            button_kf06_next = (Button) kf06_view.findViewById(R.id.button_kf06_next);
            txtVw_kf06_resident_away= (TextView) kf06_view.findViewById(R.id.txtVw_kf06_resident_away);

            radioGp_kf06_resident_away = (RadioGroup) kf06_view.findViewById(R.id.radioGp_kf06_resident_away);
            radioButtons.add( (RadioButton)kf06_view.findViewById(R.id.radio_kf06_1_2_hours) );
            radioButtons.add( (RadioButton)kf06_view.findViewById(R.id.radio_kf06_halfday) );
            radioButtons.add( (RadioButton)kf06_view.findViewById(R.id.radio_kf06_allday) );
            radioButtons.add( (RadioButton)kf06_view.findViewById(R.id.radio_kf06_moreday) );

            configClickListeners();
            radioButtonAction();



        }
        private void configClickListeners() {
            button_kf06_back.setOnClickListener(this);
            button_kf06_next.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        private void radioButtonAction(){
            for (RadioButton button : radioButtons){
                button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) processRadioButtonClick(buttonView);
                        String radio_Text = buttonView.getText().toString();
                        int radio_Id = buttonView.getId();
                        System.out.println("Selected the Radio:"+radio_Text+", Radio-Id:"+radio_Id);
                    }
                });

            }
        }

        private void processRadioButtonClick(CompoundButton buttonView){
            for (RadioButton button : radioButtons){
                if (button != buttonView ) button.setChecked(false);
            }

        }

}
```

**k06_away.xml**

```
<RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lLayout_kf06_resident_away"
            android:id="@+id/radioGp_kf06_resident_away">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                tools:ignore="UselessParent">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
                    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">
                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_kf06_1_2_hours"
                        style="@style/radionbutton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/label_resident_away_hour_1"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:paddingStart="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        tools:ignore="NestedWeights,RtlSymmetry" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_kf06_halfday"
                        style="@style/radionbutton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/label_resident_away_hour_2"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:paddingStart="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                        tools:ignore="NestedWeights,RtlSymmetry"/>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">
                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_kf06_allday"
                        style="@style/radionbutton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/label_resident_away_hour_3"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:paddingStart="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
                        tools:ignore="NestedWeights,RtlSymmetry"/>

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_kf06_moreday"
                        style="@style/radionbutton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/label_resident_away_hour_4"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:paddingStart="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                        tools:ignore="NestedWeights,RtlSymmetry,RtlHardcoded"/>


                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: call your `configViews()` method in `onCreateView()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** Try to call method `configViews()` from `onCreateView()` and pass the view `kf06_view` as parameter.

**2.** Implement `View.OnClickListener` to handle `button_kf06_back` and `button_kf06_next` click events.

**Update your `K06_Away` Fragment as below:**

```
public class K06_Away extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    protected Typeface tfLatoBold,tfLatoMedium,tfLatoRegular;
    private Button button_kf06_back,button_kf06_next;
    private TextView txtVw_kf06_resident_away;
    private EditText edTxt_kf06_visiting_lastname;
    private RadioGroup radioGp_kf06_resident_away;
    List<RadioButton> radioButtons = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View kf06_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.k06_away, container, false);

        // Init
        configViews(kf06_view);

        return kf06_view;
    }

    private void configViews(View view) {
        button_kf06_back = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_kf06_back);
        button_kf06_next = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_kf06_next);
        txtVw_kf06_resident_away= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtVw_kf06_resident_away);

        radioGp_kf06_resident_away = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGp_kf06_resident_away);
        radioButtons.add( (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio_kf06_1_2_hours) );
        radioButtons.add( (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio_kf06_halfday) );
        radioButtons.add( (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio_kf06_allday) );
        radioButtons.add( (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio_kf06_moreday) );

        configClickListeners();
        radioButtonAction();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_kf06_back:
                // Do something...
                break;
            case R.id.button_kf06_next:
                // Do something...
                break;
        }
    }

    private void configClickListeners() {
        button_kf06_back.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_kf06_next.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void radioButtonAction(){
        for (RadioButton button : radioButtons){
            button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) processRadioButtonClick(buttonView);
                    String radio_Text = buttonView.getText().toString();
                    int radio_Id = buttonView.getId();
                    System.out.println("Selected the Radio:"+radio_Text+", Radio-Id:"+radio_Id);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void processRadioButtonClick(CompoundButton buttonView){
        for (RadioButton button : radioButtons){
            if (button != buttonView ) button.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey FAT, I got a solution for my question, the actual reason is my background screen color and accent color are same, so the view was unable to show the selection. Thank you for effort, Sorry for the brain fade.

Answer (score 2):

RadioGroup Directly contain only RadioButtons,No other Layouts,if you add LinearLayout inside RadioGroup,it will not works as you expect.Only use RadioButtons as child of RadioGroup.

Comment: My design requirements for tablet 10-inch tablet screen. Any other possibilities to do on my side except this design.

Comment: You have to add each RadioButton clicklistner,then useing this clicklistner you have set other RadioButton uncheck and clicked RadioButton cheked.